# "tailing" a binary file based on string location using bash?

Tags: bash, tail, string-search

I've got a bunch of binary files, each containing an embedded string near the end of the file but at different places (only occurs once in each file).  I need to extract the part of the file starting at the location of the string till the end of the file and dump it into a new file.

eg.  If the file's contents is "AWREDEDEDEXXXERESSDSDS" and the string of interest is "XXX", then the part of the file I need is "XXXERESSDSDS".

What's the easiest way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
ls -1 *.bin | xargs strings -n4 --radix=d -f | grep "string" | awk '{sub(/:/, ""); print $2 " " $1 " " $1".";}' | xargs -l1 split -b && rm *.aa
```

**ls -1 *.bin** *Print only the filenames with the extension "bin" in a list format*

**xargs strings -n4 --radix=d -f** *List all the strings in the file and their positions and include the filename in the output*

**grep "string"** *Print lines containing "string" (it only occurs once in each file)*

**awk '{sub(/:/, ""); print $2 " " $1 " " $1".";}'** *Remove the colon after the filename added by strings, and print the position of the string, the filename, and the filename with a period (this line is used as the arguments for the split command*

**xargs -l1 split -b**  *Execute the split command for each line using the output of awk as the rest of the arguments*

**rm *.aa** *Delete the first parts of the split files.  "aa" is the default suffix for the part of the split files.*

There are probably better/faster/safer ways of doing this but it's fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In PERL, there is a variable built in that specifically refers to the part of the string after the matched regular expression.   That would be the method I would use.   It is not just Bash and utilities, but PERL is so commonly installed that you should be OK.

Comment: Most text oriented utilities in the unix standard command line handle binary data poorly and/or incorrectly as they make assumptions like no '\0' characters in the file. This is why you will have more success using a program like Perl or Python which has no such limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a small hack shell solution that is not very performant. But it works.

Write the script file `tail.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
dd bs=1 if=$1 of=$2 skip=`grep --binary-files=text -m1 -b -o $3 $1 | cut -d ':' -f 1 | head -1`
```

Call tail.sh INPUTNAME OUTPUTNAME PATTERN

*p.s.: sorry forgot one option to grep in first post*

Comment: Gives me this error: "dd: invalid number `'".  By the way, this was on a test file.  I let it run for a few minutes on a 9mb file and it didn't complete.

Comment: Well as I said it is very slow. Maybe it was even slower for you as the grep didn't work right. better try again.

Answer (score 0):

Would `strings` and `grep` do you want?

e.g.

```
strings -n 3 myfilename | grep XXX
```

Comment: It only returns the string, not the bit that follows.  I need everything from the start of the string till the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 strings -n3 file_binary | awk '/XXX/{gsub(/.*XXX/,"");print}'
```

Comment: Prints a single blank line on my system.

Comment: This output stops at the next newline character!

Comment: ... `awk '/XXX/{gsub(/.*XXX/,"");p=1}p{print}'`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
grep -ao string.* filename
```

Since you have binary data, you might want to redirect the output to a file.

```
grep -ao string.* filename > binary.out
```

Or pipe it through `hexdump` or similar for testing:

```
grep -ao string.* filename | hd
```

Comment: Thanks, it fails when it hits a newline character though.

Comment: This output stops at the next newline character!